# Can I modify the hold duration of Unity Input System's action interaction property at runtime using scripting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the new Input System and I want to create an Interaction system where I can adjust the "hold time" duration of each interaction object.

For instance: I have an object "A" where the hold duration must be 1 sec., and then an other object "B" where the hold duration must be 2 sec. So I want to change the hold duration of the Action Interaction property at runtime.

Comment: Just use a timer in a co-routine: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html. e.g. `while (true) {t += Time.deltaTime; If (t > 2).... do logic; yield return null }`

Comment: It is unclear how you would handle that on a per object basis, since the input action is the same.  Can you describe how you envision handling this logic?  [Interactions Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Interactions.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before simply do this in the according component not on the action itself

```
public class EventOnHold : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] InputActionReference actionToListenTo;
    [SerializeField] float holdTime = 1f;

    public UnityEvent onTriggered;
    public UnityEvent<float> onProgress;
    
    Coroutine routine;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        actionToListenTo.action.performed += Performed;
        actionToListenTo.action.canceled += Canceled;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        actionToListenTo.action.performed -= Performed;
        actionToListenTo.action.canceled -= Canceled;
    }

    void Performed(Inputaction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        routine = StartCoroutine(Routine());
    }

    void Canceled(Inputaction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if(routine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(routine);
            routine = null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Routine()
    {
        for(var time = 0f; time < holdTime; time += Time.deltTime)
        {
            onProgress.Invoke(time / holdTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        onProgress.Invoke(1f);
        onTriggered.Invoke();

        routine = null;
    }
}
```

and on the action itself have no hold time at all

Comment: I know I can use Coroutines, but I wanted to know if there is a way to change that interaction property to make it easier, because I also wanted to use it to create a button in the UI that shows the progress of being held down, and the action has a method that returns the progress percentage. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Joaquin well .. no, not if different objects require different hold times for the same action .... added progress to the routine